# node.js, java.stdout.on and socket, why is this variable not available to java.*.on?

Tags: node.js

I am creating a node server that upon a request, spawns a java process, and I want to dynamically pass on the java output to the client, such as showing live logging on the browser.

For this I thinking of using 'socket.emit' within 'java.stdout/err.on', using the following code structure, but 'socket' is undefined within the java block:

```
function javaSTI(userid, email, targetUrl, parserclass, selectedTableIndex, socket, fn){   
   var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
   var java = spawn('java', ['-cp', STI_LIB, STI_MAIN_CLASS, userid, email, targetUrl, STI_OUTPUT_FOLDER, parserclass, selectedTableIndex, STI_PROPERTY]);

   var error='';   
   //### this line generates error1
   socket.emit('java_sti',{msg:'ok'});

   java.stdout.on('data', function(data){          
      var txt=replaceAll('\n',data.toString(),'<br/>')+'<br/>';
      //### this line generates error2 (if the above line causing error is commented)
      socket.emit('sti_info', {msg:txt});
   });

   java.stderr.on('data', function(data){
      var txt=replaceAll('\n',data.toString(),'<br/>')+'<br/>';
      socket.emit('sti_err', {msg:txt});
   });

   var result;
   java.on('close', function(code){
      var returnWebpage=subfolder+'/'+STI_ERROR_PAGE;
      console.log('java process exited with code %s', code);
      socket.emit('sti_complete', {msg:'file to display'});
      fn(userid);
   });

}

io.of('/').on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('java_sti', function(data){
       //### this line is fine
       socket.emit('java_sti',{msg:'ok'});
       //spawn the sti java process, and pass the socket object ('this')
       javaSTI(localUserId,data.url, data.tableparserClass, data.tableIndexes, this, onSTIComplete);

  });
}
```

**Error1**:

```
Missing error handler on `socket`.
socket.js:404 TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at javaSTI (startserver.js:126:11)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (startserver.js:197:4)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Socket.onevent (/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:335:8)
    at Socket.onpacket (/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:295:12)
    at Client.ondecoded (/node_modules/socket.io/lib/client.js:193:14)
    at Decoder.Emitter.emit (/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-parser/node_modules/component-emitter/index.js:134:20)
    at Decoder.add (/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-parser/index.js:247:12)
    at Client.ondata (/node_modules/socket.io/lib/client.js:175:18)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
```

**erro2**

```
startserver.js:130
      socket.emit('sti_info', {msg:txt});
             ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Socket.<anonymous> (startserver.js:130:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:126:10)
    at Pipe.onread (net.js:538:20)
```

Is there anyway I can work around it?

Thanks

**EDIT**: just added the complete code for the function as requested

Comment: Can you show the code that calls `callJava`?

Comment: just added the complete code

Comment: I'm not sure if you should be using `this` instead of `socket` in your call to `javaSTI`. What is the actual problem that you're trying to debug?

Comment: sorry, i was not correct with my description. I just updated it hope it makes sense now. Also I tested 'socket' instead of 'this' they are the same

Answer (score 0):

Maybe problem is here?

> [child.stdout](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_class_childprocess)
>
> A Readable Stream that represents the child process's stdout. If the
>   child was spawned with `stdio[1]` set to anything other than `'pipe'`,
>   then this will be **undefined**

Comment: I doubt. the documentation says that the stream (child.stdout) will be undefined. But that is not my problem. My problem is that the 'socket' variable is undefined, only within 'java.stderr/out.on' context

Answer (score 0):

Your function takes 7 arguments:

```
function javaSTI(userid, email, targetUrl, parserclass, selectedTableIndex, socket, fn)
                 1       2      3          4            5                   6       7
```

You're only passing 6 arguments when you call it:

```
javaSTI(localUserId,data.url, data.tableparserClass, data.tableIndexes, this, onSTIComplete)
        1           2         3                      4                  5     6
```

Comment: Well spotted! Funny that I always need another pair of eyes to spot silly errors like this... thanks so much